# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Disk Partition Recomendations

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, 18.04

I upgraded to **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** and my disk partition is the following picture.

[image]

I want to have partition now. I booted with **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** CD. I need help to get proper disk partition without having any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 defaults to using a swap file instead of the previous method of having a dedicated swap partition.  This makes it easier to partition new installations of 18.04 than it was before.

Assuming you are going to do a fresh installation of 18.04, and also assuming you aren't trying to dual-boot with this same drive, here's what you should do:

1. Boot to a Ubuntu 18.04 installer (probably using a usb drive)
2. Delete the three existing partitions from your hard drive: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, and /dev/sda3.
3. Create one new partition, /dev/sda1, that uses all the available space.  Make the new partition primary (not extended), format it as ext4, and have it mount the root of the system (/).
4. Install ubuntu, selecting to put the bootloader on /dev/sda

Comment: Thanks @64pi0r for your answer.  I've already installed 18.04 so any changes you recommend. Thanks.

Comment: If you create partitions in advance you must have the ESP - efi system partition for correct UEFI boot. And drive should be gpt partitioned. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu